# Setting a value to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've run into a problem in Ruby that I can't seem to find an answer online for.
I have a few forms, and on one of them, I'm trying to set the value of `age` to `nil` if nothing is entered.
This is the relevant section for what I have right now:

```
puts "What is #{name}'s estimated age?"
age = gets.to_i

    def set_nils
        age = nil if age.blank?
    end
```

I've tried a few different ideas, but nothing seems to change my final output (just printing age back) at all.

Comment: are you calling the `set_nils` function anywhere?  It will not be called automatically, so you need to have called it prior to depending on its value.

Comment: Thanks! I've included that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you enter nothing as your input and convert this `\n` to an integer, the value becomes 0 because:

```
irb(main):008:0> '\n'.to_i
=> 0
```

Therefore, you should change to this:

```
puts "What is #{name}'s estimated age?"
input = gets.to_i
@age = input > 0 ? input : nil

def set_nils
    @age ||= nil
end
```

**Output with valid age (> 0):**

```
irb(main):001:0> name = "Tim"
=> "Tim"
irb(main):002:0> puts "What is #{name}'s estimated age?"
What is Tim's estimated age?
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> input = gets.to_i
8
=> 8
irb(main):004:0> @age = input > 0 ? input : nil
=> 8
irb(main):005:0>
irb(main):006:0* def set_nils
irb(main):007:1>     @age ||= nil
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> set_nils
=> 8
```

**Output with invalid age (< 0):**

```
irb(main):017:0> name = "Tim"
=> "Tim"
irb(main):018:0> puts "What is #{name}'s estimated age?"
What is Tim's estimated age?
=> nil
irb(main):019:0> input = gets.to_i
-1
=> -1
irb(main):020:0> @age = input > 0 ? input : nil
=> nil
irb(main):021:0>
irb(main):022:0* def set_nils
irb(main):023:1>     @age ||= nil
irb(main):024:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):025:0> set_nils
=> nil
```

Comment: Quick note, `gets` will result in `"\n"` if user inputs nothing and hits enter. But `"\n".to_i` will evaluate to `0`.

Comment: Great clarification, I will fix this.  Thank you.